# onsubmit form event returns false but $_post is populated

Tags: php

I want to know what happens to $_POST array if form onsubmit="return validate()" returns false.In my case it is getting populated.i checked its value in javascript validate function.

```
function emailValidate() {
    var result = true;
    var email = document.getElementById('newsletter');
    var field = document.getElementById('field');
    var num = 0;
    var re_Email = /([a-zA-Z_-]{3,20})+\@+([a-zA-Z]{3,10})+\.+([a-zA-Z]{2,5})$/;
    if (re_Email.test(email.value)) {} else {
        echo $_POST['email'];
        var html = "<li style='width:230px; position:relative; margin-left:15px; margin-top:10px; text-align:center; font-size:13px; background-color:green'>Invalid email</li>";
        $(html).appendTo("#field").fadeOut(3500);
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Is the form ever submitted (you are implicating it is not, so how are you checking the values)? Please provide some code examples that show the current behaviour

Comment: in js file ....function emailValidate()
{
 var result=true;
 
 var email=document.getElementById('newsletter');
 var field=document.getElementById('field');
  var num=0;
  var re_Email=/([a-zA-Z_-]{3,20})+\@+([a-zA-Z]{3,10})+\.+([a-zA-Z]{2,5})$/;
  if(re_Email.test(email.value))
 {
  
  
 }else
 {
 echo $_POST['email'];
  var html= "<li style='width:230px; position:relative; margin-left:15px; margin-top:10px; text-align:center; font-size:13px;  background-color:green'>Invalid email</li>";
  $(html).appendTo("#field").fadeOut(3500);
  
 
  
}}

Comment: You could have edited that into your question.. Also how does it prove that `$_POST` is populated?

Comment: That's Javascript, not PHP being used for the form validation. How does this concern PHP? *edit* I take it back, there is PHP in that validation rule, although, I still have no idea why.

Comment: in buynsell.php file.. <form method="post" action="buynsell.php" onsubmit="return emailValidate()">
      
      
          <input type="text" class="search_box" name="email" id="newsletter" style="width:280px; margin-left:6px; border-radius:8px"  />
      
          <input type="submit" class="search_btn" value="SIGNUP" style="width:100px; height:30px; margin-left:65px; border-radius:0;  text-align:center; background-color:#66F"  />
            
      </form>